# BLoC returns blank Stream in custom transformer

Tags: flutter, bloc, rxdart

I'm using the bloc_concurrency package and trying to return a stream based upon current event type.

What I've tried:

```
EventTransformer <ActivityEvent> customTransformer() {

    return (events, mapper) {

        Stream <ActivityEvent> activityStream =
            const Stream.empty();

        events.forEach((event) {

            if (event.eventType != QueueEvent.pausedQEvent) {

                activityStream = Stream.fromIterable([event]).asyncExpand(mapper);
            } else {

                activityStream = events.where((event) => event.eventType == QueueEvent.pausedQEvent);

            }
        });

        return activityStream;

    };

}
```

The stream always returns empty and only returns correct when explicitly returned with:

```
return events.where((event) => event.eventType != QueueEvent.pausedQEvent);
```

How can I return those two streams as per the event type? Would a switchMap work here?